# BIOS is not showing device booting list after installing ubuntu12.10 64ibt

Tags: boot, live-usb, bios

Bios is not showing device booting list after installing UBUNTU12.10 64 bit and because of which I am unable to install another OS through my bootable usb.

Installing ubuntu12.10 64 bit has changed my bios device booting list.Boot menu is only showing ubuntu.And thus I am unable to select the bootable usb drive .Please help.

Comment: Are you sure it is the BIOS? You said boot menu, that would mean Grub because installed OS will **not** be displayed on BIOS boot device list. Make sure you press either Del, Esc, F1, F2 or F10 (it depends on the computer) on boot to get to the BIOS or CMOS setup.

Comment: Yes,its bios. Ubuntu12.10 takes control of it.In order to boot from other bootable device, each time I have to restore bios configuration by pressing f9 and then only I am able to see the bootable devices in bios.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing F9 will bring you to the boot menu but that is only part of your bios function. You need to actually enter your bios setup by pressing (usually Del, F1 or F2) and select the first drive you want to boot to. The bios normally will ignore your USB unless it is clearly set to boot to it by you. You need to add it to your boot menu. If you have never entered your bios setup before I strongly urge you not to do it. Get help from a friend who knows what he is doing.